# What is `singleton_class` method in class and object?

Tags: ruby, metaclass

I defined methods `specific_data1` and `specific_data2` in meta class, and expected these methods belong to the singleton class:

```
class User
  def User.specific_data1
    "user specific data defined on user"
  end
  class << self
    def specific_data2
      "user specific data defined in meta class"
    end
  end
end
```

But neither of the methods is found in:

```
User.singleton_class.methods
```

Please help me understand what `singleton_method` on `User` class is and how it is useful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Object#methods` returns the methods of that object. Methods defined in a class aren't methods of that class object, they are methods of that class's instances.

This has nothing to do with singleton classes, it's true for all classes:

```
class Foo
  def bar; end
end

Foo.methods.include?(:bar)
# => false

Foo.new.methods.include?(:bar)
# => true

Foo.instance_methods
# => [:bar]
```

Here's how that works with your example:

```
User.methods.grep(/specific/)
# => [:specific_data1, :specific_data2]

User.singleton_methods
# => [:specific_data1, :specific_data2]

User.singleton_class.instance_methods.grep(/specific/)
# => [:specific_data1, :specific_data2]
```

Comment: You are right but my concern is why they are not appear on singleton_class object. Are they not belonging to singleton class (meta class)

Comment: They are instance methods of the singleton class, which means they are methods of instances of the singleton class, i.e. they are methods of `User`. It really works just like any other class. Instance methods of `String` are methods of instances of `String`, not the `String` class itself. You can `split` an instance of `String`, you cannot `split` the `String` class. And so on.

Comment: So User.singleton_class method returns what

Comment: It returns the singleton class of `User`.

Answer (score 0):

Both of the methods you defined are defined as instance methods on the singleton_class.

```
User.singleton_class.instance_methods(false)
# => [:specific_data1, :specific_data2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Jorg got the technical part of your question right. You want to check

```
User.singleton_class.instance_methods
```

As for this

> Please help me understand what `singleton_method` on `User` class is and how it is useful."

Suppose you have an object `x` and you want to define a method for it. One way would be to define the method in `x`'s class, but this has the side effect of defining the method for *all other objects* of that class! What if you just want to define the method for the *single* object `x`?

Ruby solves this problem by letting you create a class which has only a *single* instance: `x`. This is the singleton class. Methods defined in it will only affect `x` because the singleton class is a subclass of `x.class` and its only instance is `x`. Singleton methods are just regular methods defined in a singleton class.